# What's the point of asynchronous folder creation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand what it the point of asynchronous folder creation. For example, I may want to create a folder and then and only then use it in the rest of the application (it must therefore exist). So why would I use asynchronous mkdir?

Here's an example:

```
var fs = require("fs");

function init() {
    fs.mkdir("/path/to/the/dir", (err) => { if (err) throw err });
}

function main() {
    init()
    // I want the folder to be guaranteed to exist from here
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because *any* interaction with the file system is a (blocking) system call (usually requiring interaction with a spinning disk, which means waiting quite a bit, relative to CPU/RAM speeds), and the event loop could be doing useful work while the system call is outstanding.

By dispatching async, even if you wait for it immediately, other work (events scheduled on the event loop) can be being done while your folder is being created.

Answer (score 2):

Async allows you to do other tasks while waiting for the resource to be ready. The other task can be unrelated, like fetching some twitter data, preparing directory content, etc.

It is just an option.

Node js also allow you to do sync folder creation.

```
fs.mkdirSync(path[, options])
```